# Random delay in seconds from numericupdown in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, random, delay

I have a desktop winforms app code:

```
    Sub Delay(ByVal dblSecs As Double)
        Const OneSec As Double = 1.0# / (1440.0# * 60.0#)
        Dim dblWaitTil As Date
        Now.AddSeconds(OneSec)
        dblWaitTil = Now.AddSeconds(OneSec).AddSeconds(dblSecs)
        Do Until Now > dblWaitTil
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop
    End Sub

Private Sub btnStart_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
Webbrowser1.Navigate(TextBox1.Text)
Delay(Val(DelayText.Text))
end sub
```

What I need is to set max. delay, same from textbox by entering seconds.
I need this to be random delay number so Im stacking here, thanks for correcting my code.
Also If its possible to make it in `NumericUpDown`, as i found some topics which says textbox text property is different as `NumericUpDown` but i like it more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an inbetween class which does most of the work for you

This class would take the WebBrowser, attach to some events of it, and would refresh periodically (depending on MinimumWait / MaximumWait)

As it is using threading, it also checks if the usercontrol needs to be invoked to Refresh it and when yes, invokes the custom refresh delegate

```
Public Class Refresher
    Protected Delegate Sub RefreshNavigationDelegate(browser As WebBrowser)

    Protected Sub RefreshNavigation(browser As WebBrowser)
        If browser.InvokeRequired Then
            browser.Invoke(New RefreshNavigationDelegate(AddressOf RefreshNavigation), browser)
            Return
        End If
        browser.Refresh(WebBrowserRefreshOption.Completely)
    End Sub

    Private _isBusy As Boolean = False
    Public Property IsBusy As Boolean
        Get
            Return _isBusy
        End Get
        Protected Set(value As Boolean)
            If _isBusy = value Then
                Return
            End If
            _isBusy = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property MinimumWait As Integer = 2000

    Public Property MaximumWait As Integer = 10000

    Private refreshThread As Thread = Nothing

    Private _browser As WebBrowser
    Public Property Browser As WebBrowser
        Get
            Return _browser
        End Get
        Set(value As WebBrowser)
            If Object.Equals(_browser, value) Then
                Return
            End If
            StopRefresh()
            If _browser IsNot Nothing Then
                RemoveHandler Browser.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf DocumentComplete
                RemoveHandler Browser.Navigating, AddressOf Navigating
            End If
            _browser = value
            If _browser IsNot Nothing Then
                AddHandler Browser.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf DocumentComplete
                AddHandler Browser.Navigating, AddressOf Navigating
                AddHandler Browser.ProgressChanged, AddressOf ProgressChanged
            End If
            StartRefresh()
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Sub ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs)
        IsBusy = e.CurrentProgress > 0 AndAlso e.CurrentProgress < e.MaximumProgress
    End Sub

    Protected Sub DocumentComplete(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
        IsBusy = False
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Navigating(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs)
        IsBusy = True
    End Sub

    Public Sub StartRefresh()
        If refreshThread IsNot Nothing Then
            Return
        End If
        refreshThread = New Thread(AddressOf DoRandomRefreshes)
        refreshThread.Start()
    End Sub

    Public Sub StopRefresh()
        If refreshThread Is Nothing Then
            Return
        End If
        refreshThread.Abort()
        refreshThread = Nothing
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub DoRandomRefreshes()
        Dim randomGenerator As New Random()

        While Not refreshThread.ThreadState = ThreadState.AbortRequested
            Dim newTimeout As Integer = MinimumWait + randomGenerator.Next(MaximumWait - MinimumWait)
            Thread.Sleep(newTimeout)
            If Not IsBusy Then
                RefreshNavigation(Browser)
            End If
        End While
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub
End Class
```

You could then use it in your form as such:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim myRefresher As Refresher = New Refresher()

    Private Sub tsbGo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tsbGo.Click
        WebBrowser1.Navigate(txtUrl.Text)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        myRefresher.Browser = WebBrowser1
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtMin_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtMin.TextChanged
        Dim int As Integer = 0
        If Integer.TryParse(txtMin.Text, int) Then
            myRefresher.MinimumWait = int
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtMax_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtMax.TextChanged
        Dim int As Integer = 0
        If Integer.TryParse(txtMax.Text, int) Then
            myRefresher.MaximumWait = int
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you very much; I go to try it and if it will do the job; I will mark your answer. Happy New Year btw :)

Comment: I tried to implement all class you wrote but I get some error here: 'AbortRequested' is not a member of 'System.Diagnostics.ThreadState'. Could yopu help pls? Thanks

Comment: What version of .net are you targetting? It should be from the `System.Threading` namespace i thought. Worst case scenario, you could simply create a private bool that has "StopRequested" and you check if it isn't true, that should also work

Comment: I got 4.5 .Net target from property, lso I declared Private boalen as stoprequest but same error, see image:http://postimg.org/image/6188b0l6z/ thansk fpor any solution

Comment: It should be from `System.Threading.ThreadState.AbortRequested`

Comment: ok now the error gone, but while i try to enter some url and hit GO btn it doesnt do anything just loaded half page and then nothing, no refresh, not delay :( Did you understand I wanted NumericUpDown and not TextBox? thanks

Comment: Change the MinimumWait & MaximumWait of the refresher class, and make sure your Browser is attached to the property of the refresher class, for the rest, use breakpoints, try to see why it didn't go. NumericUpDown and TextBoxes, if you can't figure that one out yourself then i'm loosing my time here

Comment: I know differnet between Textboxes and NumericUpDown, but sometimes i saw the property .text Is not in NumericUpDown, thats why I wanted make sure. Sorry if you feel you loosing time with me I really appreciate soemoen  answering me correctly, I just asking many times same just to make sure and put it in my head it is the way i learn. OK I try the chanegs I let you know in a minute thx

Comment: Get this: http://postimg.org/image/erai7q09f/ Aslo What you meant by: "Change the MinimumWait & MaximumWait of the refresher class, and make sure your Browser is attached to the property of the refresher class" ? thanks

Comment: I mark this as answered even through it doesn't refresh my webbrowser with delay as I wanted, just because I see you put effort in help to me, so thanks anyway but It doesn't refresh at all with delay so no prob I keep looking, thanks again

Comment: Could you show your form1.vb? if you are anyhow posting stuff? Did you attach everything as in the example? Is the URL you are surfing to valid, and working?

Comment: Ok like this I create Form1 and add code for form1 you mentioned, then I add class to my project and rename it like you mention and add code, thats all. I have this form design: http://postimg.org/image/htweyfzvt/

Comment: You do notice that you wrote `http:/www.google.uk` with only 1 `/` instead of 2? Furthermore, 10 ms seconds is not a delay, if you wish 10 seconds, then it has to be 10 * 1000 = 10.000 miliseconds, Your very short delay, is indeed not a huge delay

Comment: I enter 10 in the minimum as I think 10 = 10.000 ms so as I has a code that convert Val 10 to 10.000ms, So I was thinking it is automatic 10 seconds. So what should I change now?

Comment: Look i don't see your screen, i cannot work with your solution, so it's hard for me to fix stuff (which you should be able to fix yourself), check the values, set breakpoints in your code (like eg, inside the DoRandomRefreshes() method, check how much time is given to the sleep parameter (that would be the newTimeout variable)). Check at runtime what is MinimumWait & MaximumWait inside the Refresher instance, it's important to learn how to debug application, you will be doing it a lot (if i speak from my experience)

Comment: Ok thanks It is working now, so it doesn't matter ms or sec :) i can also enter 10.000 and not only 10 so yes thank very much for help ! Also could you please see this screen : http://postimg.org/image/o3h6oxojl/ as I want only refresh loop not always I mean i want to enter lets say from textbox 10 loops, so what should I change in my Refresher class?

Comment: Then add a counter inside the DoRandomRefreshes() method that increases on each loop through run, and use the same setup as MinimumWait & MaximumWait to send it to the refresher class

Comment: just one more question, how do I stop refresher class with button? I tried to add just "StopRefresh()" but it is not declared in form its only in class, so im lil bit confused, I would like also ask more question, but it seems im blocked here from asking question :( dont know why and what i did, so it is not fair.

Comment: Just as an info, @jane1990, Offcourse it is fair that you are blocked for a short period. As I remember the first comments you made on your post, there was a lot of insulting and provocation coming from you, just check your own profile. If you feel that you are unfairly handled, then please ask a mod instead of being as loud as you possibly can. BTW once your question will be deleted, you will be able to ask questions again